# Create object from another one Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object {key: 'Mother', value: 'Mam'}.
I need to get an object like {'Mother': 'Mam'}

Comment: First I tried to do something like const obj =  {key: 'Mother', value: 'Mam'}. And then const newOne = {obj.key : obj.value}. But it was a really stupid attempt. Then I tried using Object.defineProperty and failed again( I'm feeling that I'm stuck in very simple place

Comment: You're basically there: {[obj.key]: obj.value}. If you want to use a variable as a key, you need bracket notation. Not dot notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is pretty vague but you could do:

```js
const obj1 = {key: 'Mother', value: 'Mam'}
const obj2 = {[obj1.key]: obj1.value}

// obj2: {Mother: 'Mam'}
```